# Calling static method without passing parameters

Tags: c#

I have this code (its just part, entire code works just fine):

```
internal static Rule<IWorkflowModel> Get()
{
    var rule = new Rule<IWorkflowModel>("Argument Naming Rule", RuleId, Inspect)
    {
        DefaultErrorLevel = System.Diagnostics.TraceLevel.Warning,
        RecommendationMessage = Recommendation
    };
    
    return rule;
}

private static InspectionResult Inspect(IWorkflowModel workflowModel, Rule ruleInstance)
{
```

I am trying to understand, how can we pass `Inspect` static method as parameter in line 3, without adding parameters to itself (like `Inspect(paramA, paramB)`?

I can guess it takes both `Rule` and `IWorkflowModel` objects from the rule created itself (line 3). But trying to figure out some logic/rule behind it.

Edit

This is `Rule<T>` class from metadata

```
namespace UiPath.Studio.Activities.Api.Analyzer.Rules
{
    public sealed class Rule<T> : Rule where T : IInspectionObject
    {
        public Rule(string ruleName, string ruleId, Func<T, Rule, InspectionResult> inspectionFunction);

        public Func<T, Rule, InspectionResult> Inspect { get; }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `Rule`? Can you show the definition for that?

Comment: What's the signature for that `Rule<T>` constructor? Or is that the question? It will probably be something like a `Func<IWorkflowModule, Rule, InspectionResult>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're passing the function, not invoking it. This allows a different piece of code to invoke the function later, supplying the arguments.

The way this is done in C# is through delegates (since about .NET 3.5, instead of using custom delegate types, you will probably want to use `Action` and `Func` respectively). You can think of a delegate as a single-method interface - it's basically a bridge between object-oriented and true functional programming.

In older code, this was mainly used in events and callbacks. Today, as C# gets more and more functional, it's getting rather common for abstract functions to accept functions as arguments; LINQ was probably the first big example. You supply your own *behaviour* to other functions. You want to filter a collection? Just pass a function that does the filtering (`col.Where(i => i.Name.Length > 3)`).

To show you a possible way of implementing what you're seeing in your code:

```
public class Rule<T> : Rule
{
  private readonly Func<T, Rule, InspectionResult> _inspect;

  public Rule(string name, string ruleId, Func<T, Rule, InspectionResult> inspect)
    : base(name, ruleId)
  {
    _inspect = inspect;
  }

  public InspectionResult Inspect(T model) => _inspect(this, model);
}
```

Note that when `Rule<T>` calls the delegate, it must supply all of the arguments.

Of course, the actual behaviour of the caller can be essentially arbitrary. The point is that you're passing a behaviour to someone else. Delegates are a very simple and quick way of doing that, especially combined with anonymous functions and all that.